# How to add logging to Windows Event Log using system.diagnostics

Tags: c#, wcf, biztalk, event-log, system.diagnostics

I created custom WCF LOB Adapter. And I'm using Trace class in it.
I would like BizTalk server to write log from that adapter to Windows Event Log.

When I add below section to BizTalk host config file BizTalk doesn't start. What is wrong with it?

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true">
  <sources>  
    <source name="AzureServiceBusClient" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing">  
      <listeners>  
        <add name="AzureServiceBusTraceListener" />  
      </listeners>  
    </source>  
  </sources>  
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="AzureServiceBusTraceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="BizTalk Server" />       
    </sharedListeners>
</trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

This is how my trace class is created in code:

```
//
// Initializes a new instane of  Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.AdapterTrace using the specified name for the source
//
static AdapterTrace trace = new AdapterTrace("AzureServiceBusClient");
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the Windows Event Log when you try starting the Host Instance?  Also you say you are trying to send to Windows Event Log, but you appear to be using an Azure Service Bus Trace Listener, can you explain this discrepancy?

Comment: Also should the listener be `initializeData="TraceListenerLog"` rather than `initializeData="BizTalk Server"`?

Comment: Can you clarify?  Did you write a custom Binding to be used with the WCF Custom or are you trying to add write Event Log Events from an existing Adapter/Binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sources should be a separate item to the trace, rather than nested as you have them.  I think you must have forgotten to self terminate the trace tag, and then added the end tag in, making it invalid.

Correcting it to the below should hopefully fix your BizTalk not starting.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>  
        <source name="AzureServiceBusClient" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing">  
            <listeners>  
                <add name="AzureServiceBusTraceListener" />  
            </listeners>  
        </source>  
    </sources>  
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="AzureServiceBusTraceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="BizTalk Server" />       
    </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Below example from [Diagnostic Tracing and Message Logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185303(v=bts.10).aspx)

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name ="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name ="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" 
              switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing">        
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name ="System.Runtime.Serialization" switchValue="Verbose">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
   </sources>
   <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"              
           traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack" 
           initializeData="C:\log\WCFTrace.svclog" />
   </sharedListeners>
   <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging 
           logEntireMessage="true" 
           logMalformedMessages="false"
           logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
           logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"/>
    </diagnostics>    
  </system.serviceModel>
```